# converting image name extension from .PNG to .png in Python

Tags: python

I have large set of images with .PNG extension (say image00.PNG). I want to convert it into .png (lower case). I got a script from internet, but am unable to process.

Here's the script:

```
files = os.listdir(cur_dir)
for filename in files:
    file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if old_ext == file_ext:
        newfile = filename.replace(old_ext, new_ext)
        os.rename(filename, newfile)
```

When I try to run it on the terminal, I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you aren't showing us the real code.

Comment: when running the code you post, I've got a "old_ext" is not defined, that is true...show us the real code ;)

Comment: Now, look in the traceback which shows line numbers and start debugging. Btw, I also got a `NameError: name 'os' is not defined` in addition to the above ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it works for real (and not rename PNGX.PNG into pngX.png ;) ) :

```
import os

files = os.listdir(".")
for filename in files:
    file_wo_ext, file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if file_ext == ".PNG":
        newfile = file_wo_ext + ".png"
        os.rename(filename, newfile)
```

Comment: i think last line is going to throw `WindowsError:`, you need to append the parent directory path.

Comment: also you need to append parent directory path with newfile otherwise it will move the file to current working directory during renaming process.

Comment: @AamirAdnan : I tested the script with PNG files under current directory, and it renamed all the files wo errors, maybe there is a case I didn't see.

Answer (score 0):

If the current working directory is not `cur_dir`, it fails. That's because `os.listdir()` returns only the list of filenames, without path. You should change to

```
os.rename(os.path.join(cur_dir, filename), os.path.join(cur_dir, newfile))
```

.

Comment: OUCH! That could be an error which surely comes later (why I let it be there as an answer) - but is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `old_ext` to `.PNG` and `new_ext` to `.png`.

Answer (score 0):

lets do it this way:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(cur_dir):
    file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if file_ext == '.PNG':
        newfile = filename.replace(file_ext, '.png')
        os.rename(cur_dir+'/'+filename, cur_dir+'/'+newfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use that when I want to lower all files extensions:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    file_ext_low = file_ext.lower()
    newfile = filename.replace(file_ext, file_ext_low)
    os.rename(directory+'/'+filename, directory+'/'+newfile)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is a python script.  Do the following if you want to use python

```
$ python
> import os
> old_ext = "PNG"
> new_ext = "png"
> files = os.listdir(cur_dir)
> for filename in files:
>   file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
>   if old_ext == file_ext: 
>      newfile = filename.replace(old_ext, new_ext)
>      os.rename(filename, newfile)
>
>
>exit()
```

But this hawkish and probably won't work.

I'd do this

```
$ rename .PNG .png *.PNG
```

via [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html)